# PHP. Вывести количество строк из листа по значению

Tags: php, сортировка

Имеется список json

```
[{"id":"1", "date":"2020-07-15"},{"id":"2", "date":"2020-07-12"}, {"id":"3", "date":"2020-05-10"},...]
```

Необходимо вытянуть количество строк с определенным месяцем и записать в переменные по месяцам

```
$m1
$m2
$m3
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот собственно первое что пришло на ум. Я бы вам посоветовал хранить кол-во месяцев в массиве, а не в 12ти переменных, но не суть.

```
<?php //php 7.2.24

    echo "Hello, world! ";
    $json_array = [["id"=>"1", "date"=>"2020-07-15"],["id"=>"2", "date"=>"2020-07-12"],["id"=>"3", "date"=>"2020-05-10"]];
    $mb1=0;
    $mb2=0;
    $mb3=0;
    $mb4=0;
    $mb5=0;
    $mb6=0;
    $mb7=0;
    $mb8=0;
    $mb9=0;
    $mb10=0;
    $mb11=0;
    $mb12=0;
foreach($json_array as $var){
    $month = explode('-',$var['date'])[1];
    switch ($month) {
    case "01":
        $mb1++;
        break;
    case "02":
        $mb2++;
        break;
    case "03":
        $mb3++;
        break;
    case "04":
        $mb4++;
        break;
    case "05":
        $mb5++;
        break;
    case "06":
        $mb6++;
        break;
    case "07":
        $mb7++;
        break;
    case "08":
        $mb8++;
        break;
    case "09":
        $mb9++;
        break;
    case "10":
        $mb10++;
        break;
    case "11":
        $mb11++;
        break;
    case "12":
        $mb12++;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```